# R dplyr - Rearrange columns by pattern of names

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, reshape, data-manipulation

I've got some long format data that 1) needs to be reshaped to wide and then 2) needs the columns resorted according pattern of their names. The example data is below:

```
#Orignial data
set.seed(100)
long_df <- tibble(id = rep(1:5, each = 3),
                  group = rep(c('g1','g2','g3'), times = 5),
                  mean = runif(15, min = 1, max = 10),
                  sd = runif(15, min = .025, max = 1))
long_df

# A tibble: 15 x 4
      id group  mean    sd
   <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 g1     3.77 0.677
 2     1 g2     3.32 0.224
 3     1 g3     5.97 0.374
 4     2 g1     1.51 0.375
 5     2 g2     5.22 0.698
 6     2 g3     5.35 0.547
 7     3 g1     8.31 0.718
 8     3 g2     4.33 0.550
 9     3 g3     5.92 0.755
10     4 g1     2.53 0.435
11     4 g2     6.62 0.192
12     4 g3     8.94 0.776
13     5 g1     3.52 0.885
14     5 g2     4.59 0.560
15     5 g3     7.86 0.296

#Reshaped to wide
wide_df <- long_df %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = 'group', values_from = c('mean','sd'))
wide_df

# A tibble: 5 x 7
     id mean_g1 mean_g2 mean_g3 sd_g1 sd_g2 sd_g3
  <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    3.77    3.32    5.97 0.677 0.224 0.374
2     2    1.51    5.22    5.35 0.375 0.698 0.547
3     3    8.31    4.33    5.92 0.718 0.550 0.755
4     4    2.53    6.62    8.94 0.435 0.192 0.776
5     5    3.52    4.59    7.86 0.885 0.560 0.296

#Wide with proper column order
final_df <- wide_df %>% 
  select(id, mean_g1, sd_g1, mean_g2, sd_g2, mean_g3, sd_g3)
final_df

# A tibble: 5 x 7
     id mean_g1 sd_g1 mean_g2 sd_g2 mean_g3 sd_g3
  <int>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1     1    3.77 0.677    3.32 0.224    5.97 0.374
2     2    1.51 0.375    5.22 0.698    5.35 0.547
3     3    8.31 0.718    4.33 0.550    5.92 0.755
4     4    2.53 0.435    6.62 0.192    8.94 0.776
5     5    3.52 0.885    4.59 0.560    7.86 0.296
```

Does someone know a way to either a) pivot the long data with the output being in the proper order or b) use a regex or sort variable to reorder the columns into the desired order? A tidyverse style solution would be preferred, but other approaches are welcome too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run `ends_with` successively on a character vector of the numeric suffixes:

```
long_df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=group, values_from=c(mean, sd)) %>% 
  select(id, ends_with(as.character(1:3)))
```

> ```
>      id mean_g1 sd_g1 mean_g2 sd_g2 mean_g3 sd_g3
>   <int>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
> 1     1    3.77 0.677    3.32 0.224    5.97 0.374
> 2     2    1.51 0.375    5.22 0.698    5.35 0.547
> 3     3    8.31 0.718    4.33 0.550    5.92 0.755
> 4     4    2.53 0.435    6.62 0.192    8.94 0.776
> 5     5    3.52 0.885    4.59 0.560    7.86 0.296
> ```

This might need the development version of `dplyr` to work (`devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")`). I'm running the development version and haven't checked this code with the current CRAN release.

You can also `pivot_longer` to the "longest" version of the data frame and then `pivot_wider` to get the desired column order without resorting:

```
long_df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=c(mean, sd)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=c(name, group), values_from=value)
```

> ```
>      id mean_g1 sd_g1 mean_g2 sd_g2 mean_g3 sd_g3
>   <int>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
> 1     1    3.77 0.677    3.32 0.224    5.97 0.374
> 2     2    1.51 0.375    5.22 0.698    5.35 0.547
> 3     3    8.31 0.718    4.33 0.550    5.92 0.755
> 4     4    2.53 0.435    6.62 0.192    8.94 0.776
> 5     5    3.52 0.885    4.59 0.560    7.86 0.296
> ```

Comment: The groups in my actual data don't have successive ordering rather they are mean_15482, mean_89652, ..., but the second solution did work. I realized I forgot to add an additional subgrouping variable, but I was able to adapt the code such the pivot to longest and then to desired wide format did work. Thank you.